# The penny dropped slowly

Tags: phrase-requests, popular-refrains, german

In Germany we have the saying "der Groschen ist gefallen", which exists in the English language, too:

> The penny dropped.

But there is also a variation for slower thinking, "der Groschen fällt pfennigweise", which would correspond to:

> Ten pence drop a penny at a time.

Is there any saying like this in English?

Comment: Off-topic question: I've never heard "der Groschen fällt pfennigweise" and I rarely hear "der Groschen ist gefallen" since having another currency. Would you say this phrasing (with *pfennigweise*) is common in your region?

Comment: I would say it is common in my peer group. "Many" people say "Der Groschen fällt centweise" too :-) But you are right, it is not common in Berlin I would say

Comment: I thought that the penny dropping already _did_ have the meaning of a slow working brain. Anyway, it doesn't have much to do with the currency in use nowadays. We still use "kwartje" here, even though there are no more quarters.

Comment: You are right. We use the saying, e.g. if you are in a group of 5, one tells a story, three understand them after explaining, the last one after two or three times explaining :)

Comment: A `Groschen` is ten `Pfenning` and it means one `Pfenning` drops after another. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent that I've ever encountered.

In English you'd use expressions like:

He's slow on the uptake.
He's slow to catch on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "Ten cents dropped *penny by penny*"